# C# Asp.net Ajaxcontroltoolkit multiple Accordion Panels. Show or Hide last panel if a checkbox is selected in first panel

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordion1" CssClass="accordion" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" AutoSize="None" RequireOpenedPane="false" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" runat="server"> 
<Panes>   
<ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="Pane1" runat="server">
    <Header><b>Panel 1</b></Header>
      <Content>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>          
            <br>
            Age: <asp:textbox id="Age1" runat="server" Width="35" Font-Bold="True"/><br>
            Attorney: <asp:CheckBox ID="Attorney" runat="server" /><br>
            <asp:button ID="Button1" text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"
            runat="server"/><br>
            <asp:label id="Message1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True"/>                
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>

    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="Pane2" runat="server">
        <Header><b>Panel 2</b></Header>
        <Content>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>                    
                <br>
                <asp:textbox id="Age2" runat="server" Width="35" Font-Bold="True"/><br>
                <asp:button ID="Button2" text="Submit" onclick="Button2_Click"
                runat="server"/><br><br>
                <asp:label id="Message2" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
```

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Attorney.Checked) {
            Pane2.Visible = true;
        } else {
            Pane2.Visible = false;
        }
        //Message1.Text = Age1.Text;
    }
```

I have five Accordion Panels. Last Panel should be displayed only if a checkbox is checked in the first panel. Inside each Accordion Panel I have a UpdatePanel and within that I have ContentTemplate with controls and submit button particular to that accordion panel. The reason I added UpdatePanel is so that when i update a particular panel it does not affect other accordion panels.

The problem is I need to toggle last accordion panel display depending upon if a checkbox is checked in the first Panel and submit button is clicked. In Code behind, in the btnSubmit1 event...I have code that says if checkbox is checked....Pane2.Visible = true else Pane2.Visible=false. For some reasons it still shows the LastPanel.

I am not sure where am I going wrong...please advise!

Thanks!
Jini

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by adding an outer update panel...and removed the updatepanel for Panel 2. Haven't tested it thoroughly but so far looks good.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="OuterPanel" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordion1" CssClass="accordion" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" AutoSize="None" RequireOpenedPane="false" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" runat="server"> 
<Panes>   
    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="Pane1" runat="server">
    <Header><b>Panel 1</b></Header>
      <Content>            
            <br>
            Age: <asp:textbox id="Age1" runat="server" Width="35" Font-Bold="True" /><br />
            Attorney: <asp:CheckBox ID="Attorney" runat="server" /><br>
            <asp:button ID="Button1" text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"
            runat="server"/><br>
            <asp:label id="Message1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True"/>                                                            
        </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>        
    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="Pane2" runat="server">
        <Header><b>Panel 2</b></Header>
        <Content>                            
                <br>
                <asp:textbox id="Age2" runat="server" Width="35" Font-Bold="True"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:button ID="Button2" text="Submit" onclick="Button2_Click"
                runat="server"/><br><br>
                <asp:label id="Message2" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" />                
        </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
 </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: it would be better if you can provide a technical explanation as to why the previous didn't work and why yours working

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see your code to be sure, but I'm expecting it's because you have an `UpdatePanel` in each of the `AccordionPanels`.  Once an event happens in one `UpdatePanel`, ASP.NET will not run code handling that event that is attached to another `UpdatePanel`.

First, I'd take out all `UpdatePanel`s to see if your code works as expected.  Then, I'd add one `UpdatePanel` wrapped around the entire `Accordion` and see if your code still works.

If you really decided you need to have 5 `UpdatePanel`s, look into the `<Triggers>` portion of the `UpdatePanel`.  You'll be able to provide the `CheckBox`'s ID to force the other associated `UpdatePanel` to PostBack.

Comment: I have added the code. I have tried adding Triggers etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Yes. I am using JQuery under that UpdatePanel to determine if the user made any changes. Only if they did I activate the First Panel Button. Without removing UpdatePanel how can I make it work?

Comment: What about `<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>` in Pane2's `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: I tried that too in Pane2's UpdatePanel. I get "A control with ID 'Button1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'."

Comment: That's what I expected--since Button1 is nested in an AccordionPanel, Pane2 can't see it.  I'd suggest using jQuery to hide it instead.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But same thing happens when I try to set the visibility for last panel via jquery. It can't seem to find Pane2.